# Notice: Undefined index: mydept in C:\xampp\htdocs\misitio\funcion\usuario.php on line 8

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este código que muestra los datos del usuario como su nombre, email, constraseña,etc.

Todos los datos estan en 2 tablas. 1 se llama usuario donde esta el id,nombre,email y tipodeusuario y el otro se llama usuario2 donde esta la contraseña y my dept.

Pero el dato de "mydept" no la logra tomar y yo necesito mantener este dato en varias paginas. Por ejemplo: si entra a su perfil tiene que obtener este dato o si entra a modificar sus datos.

```
 function misdatos()
    {
        $link = conectar();
        $mydept = $_POST ['mydept'];
        $mysql = "SELECT us.usuarioid, us.nombre, us.email, us.tipodeusuario, ue.contrasena, ue.mydept
                    FROM usuario AS us
                    INNER JOIN usuario2 AS ue
                    ON us.usuarioid = ue.usuarioid 
                    WHERE ue.mydept = '".$mydept."' ORDER BY us.usuarioid DESC";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($link, $mysql);
        return $result1;
    }
```

**la linea 8 es `$mydept = $_POST ['mydept'];`**

> Notice: Undefined index: mydept in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\misitio\funcion\usuario.php on line 8

Una forma que encontre en google es agregando isset `$mydept = isset($_POST ['mydept']);` pero creo que solo lo oculta, yo necesito que tome este dato y lo mantenga.

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($_POST);` para verificar lo que hay en el POST. Si usas un formulario éste debe tener un elemento con `name="mydept"` para que el dato se encuentre en el POST y no estar vacío al enviar el formulario. SI pasas los datos por la URL, igual, debe haber un parámetro `mydept` con datos. O, si mandas un objeto desde Ajax lo mismo, éste debe tener una propiedad `mydept` con datos. En PHP, para controlar eso puedes usar un ternario donde verifiques con `empty()`, así asignas el dato o `NULL` en una variable y luego verificas/usas esa variable,

Comment: Un error que encontre es que no tendria que usar `POST` sino `GET`, porque estoy queriendo que obtenga datos, no que postee en un formulario. Ahi intente con `var_dump` pero sigue igual con la suma de `NULL` al final de todo. Esto es lo que escribi `$mydept = var_dump($_GET ['mydept']);`

Comment: Detalle mínimo pero quita ese espacio entre get y el valor asociado, no tiene por que tenerlo

Comment: Ahi probe con ternario `$mydept = empty($_GET['mydept']) ? 'No hay datos' : $_GET['mydept'];` . El problema ya no aparece, pero como se que el dato lo esta tomando?

Comment: Pon `var_dump($_GET);` sin nada, para depurar, no para asignar el valor.

Answer (score 0):

ahi probe con de esta forma y toma el dato y lo guarda. En caso de que no tenga nada asignado te avisa.

```
$mydept = (isset($_SESSION['mydept']) ? $_SESSION['mydept '] : "Sin departamento asignado");
```

Comment: ¿Esto resuelve el problema? ¿Por qué ahora cambiaste a session?

Comment: **(No soy un profesional en php pero me imagino que hace esto)**: Cuando te logueas consulta a la tabla cuales son los datos y si coinciden. Entonces, de la misma forma que pregunta cual es tu nombre para mostrar en "Tu perfil", aca hace algo parecido . _(Puede que me equivoque, si es asi corríjanme)_